# Best Element for Draggable location bar.

Tags: html, css, markup

I'm creating an app that contains a draggable location bar. This element would allow you to drag thru chapters in a book and be seen at the bottom of the viewport. Much like Kindle or other mobile reading apps.

[image: Shot of the location bar]

I'd like to hear your thoughts on what element to use.

```
<progress>
```

element, or was also thinking about using

```
<input type="range">
```

Or should we just roll our own and throw some javascript at it?

Comment: `number` or `range` are inputs that would satisfy your use case. `progress` is not intended for user input: would be fine if you only wanted to display position in the book, not change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically, your use case is best answered by the [`number`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/#input-number) or [`range`](http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/#input-range) input types

```
<input type="number" max="50" min="1" value="10">
<input type="range" max="50" min="1" step="1" value="10">
```

The challenge is in styling.

[Filament Group](http://filamentgroup.com/dwpe/) have done some interesting work around making accessible slider controls for a variety of inputs, including number: http://filamentgroup.com/dwpe/slider/

Code on Github: https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Slider

Comment: yea, this is certainly a challenge because I wanted this to serve two purposes which is show progress in the book, as well as be able to change the location. Dual functions I suppose. I'll see how far I can get with styling up an input range. Thanks!